# Convert a text file into an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, file, arraylist

I would like to extract the information saved in a text file and convert it into an ArrayList. The file is formed by a number to distingue the line and the String atributte. The problem is that I don´t know how to convert encuestas to an array and that it says that the variables might not have been initialized when I try listas.add.

```
public Lista Cargar_Listas(){ 
    ArrayList <Militante> militantes= new ArrayList <>();
    Lista lista = new Lista(militantes);

    try{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("archivo.txt");
        BufferedReader entrada = new BufferedReader(fr);

        int j=0;
        String s;
        String nombrem, apellidos, profesion, siglas_partido, carne;
        int edad;
        char genero;
        double cuota;
        String[] encuesta;

        while((s=entrada.readLine())!=null){

            if(j==0) nombrem=s;
            if(j==1) apellidos=s;
            if(j==2) edad=Integer.parseInt(s);
            if(j==3) profesion=s;
            if(j==4) genero=s.charAt(0);
            if(j==5) siglas_partido=s;
            if(j==6) encuesta={s};
            if(j==7) cuota=Double.parseDouble(s);               
            if(j==8) carne=s;


            j++; 

           if(j>8){
               j=0;
               lista.add(new Militante(nombrem, apellidos, edad, profesion, genero, siglas_partido, encuesta, cuota, carne));
           }
        }
        entrada.close();
    }
    catch(java.io.FileNotFoundException fnfex){
       System.out.println("Archivo no encontrado: "+fnfex);}
    catch(java.io.IOException ioex){}
    return lista;
}
```

Comment: What type of class is `Lista`? Why can't you use `militantes.add()`?

Comment: Please also post some sample data.

Comment: @cricket_007 Lista is ArrayList <Militante> elementos. I have tried with militantes.add() too but it does not work

Comment: If it complains about non-initialized variables, you can just pre-initialize them if you are sure they will be overwritten / initialized later anyways.  (I.e. `String nombrem = ""; String apellidos = ""; ..`)

Comment: @AndrewMcCoist It is just a normal add, I haven´t overwriten it so far

Comment: `militantes.add()` should work fine. What exactly didn't work?

Comment: You *are* skipping a line. You should change the if statement to `if (j % 8 == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
What does the seventh line of the input look like:  Is it a comma separated line?
Use:

```
encuesta = s.split(",");
```

Or, your problem is probably in the Militante class.
It probably contains a List<> encuesta, and the Constructor probably expects a List.
However you are passing a String[].

Try:

```
militantes.add(new Militante(nombrem, apellidos, edad, profesion, genero, siglas_partido, Arrays.asList(encuesta), cuota, carne)));
```

If this doesn't work, please edit your post to add the Militante class.
Thank you.

Comment: How can you post this as an answer if you don't know what the constructor of `Militante` looks like?